# Mapping error in Azure Data Factory (connecting JSON in Blob storage to Azure SQL table)

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I am trying to map a JSON output (in Blob storage) into Azure SQL table (inside Azure Data Factory).

Currently, my JSON file looks like this:

I validated the JSON format of the output file at https://jsonlint.com/, and it looks fine ("Valid Json").

[image]

This is setting that I did for JSON file.

[image]

This is screenshot when I preview source data (JSON):

I am not sure why it shows as this (having row with "Prop_0".):
[image]

This is result when I try to map to Azure SQL table:

[image]

What could be the reason that JSON file does not show up with each columns (like "VENDORID", "VENDORNAME", "TOTALPAID" etc.) when I try to connect "Copy data" and map Json file (in Blob storage) to Azure SQL table?

**This is additional image after I changed the output file from txt file with .JSON extension to purely JSON file:**
[image]

This is an error message due to mapping issue (txt --> JSON):
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the sample JSON file

Comment: You don't have to share the file here if it has sensitive information. I have used a similar JSON file in the example in my answer below, do try make changes and let me know

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT  Thank you for your help. Here is safe JSON file.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ErSv0Geh5NVdl2oaj640arfxJwie5LXp/view?usp=sharing  Thank you!

Comment: Was my answer helpful ?

Comment: @KarthikBhyresh-MT I was able to solve the issue by having next "Copy data" pointing to the same csv (text) file as JSON format. This one was very tricky. Next time, I should not delete any previous Pipeline that I created. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have, **CSV** as dataset type created for source, wheras it is a **JSON** file --> **APBILL_output.json**

While Creating Source data set for CopyActivity, you would have to choose dataset type as **JSON**

[image]

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: I am trying to understand where I should "choose dataset type as JSON". Sorry, the animation is little fast and I am not able to follow. When I check the file at Blob storage, it shows as json file. But, I dragged the "Copy data" and tried to create a pipeline, it shows up as csv file. I basically followed this YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSLnffz3_1M&list=PLHdddESbFFCKyPvEJ56oisGTErSgFvTw_&index=2), and at 9 min:30sec of this video and it mentioned about selecting CSV "DelimitedText" file to create and then later rename the file to JSON.

Comment: checking... So according to the video that you mention, at 09:12 instead of choosing CSV as format for sink datset, please choose JSON. The video maybe refering to a specific scenario which might not be necessary for you to follow

Comment: As in my example, you have to select the **Source Dataset format** as **JSON** for the **Copy data2** Activity in your pipeline

Comment: As in the video the user has asked to name the file as .json the file created in Blob Storage says Json but the format is csv in the linked service. It is reading JSON as a CSV. which is causing error.

Comment: Actually, I created the "Copy data2" like what video illustrated, and it worked earlier (2 wks ago). Unfortunately, I accidentally deleted what I created earlier. But, I will try again with selecting Source Dataset format as JSON since you mentioned it. Thank you!

Comment: sure, let me know if any issues

Comment: I modified the output file type to JSON. Now, the issue is mapping from input file which is in text file. I updated the original post with additional images to illustrate. It is strange that it worked (moved data from Copy data1 --> Copy data2) using text file as output, last week, but now, it does not work.

Comment: I opened a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660248/how-to-move-data-from-response-of-http-json-data-to-a-json-file-using-azure-da) because I am trying to find a solution for whole pipeline. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution by having the data type of JSON on next "Copy data" pointing to the text file (csv) that I used. Even though the file was originally created with DelimitedText (csv) file, when I pointed that same file, but using JSON format, it took it.
Then, rest process (mapping to SQL table) worked as expected :)
[image]