# How to move data from response of Http (JSON data) to a JSON file

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I am trying to build an Azure Data Factory pipeline where it copies the Response of Output (JSON format) from Azure Function and move its data to a JSON file.

I am ***not*** using REST API.

[image]

Initially, I built a pipeline where it used Variable to copy the data into a **Text file**.
[image]

Now, I am trying to move data into a **JSON file** so that I could map JSON file's columns to SQL table.

What is best architecture of this data pipeline?

Do I need a **Text file** from moving data of "output.Response" (from 1st step) to JSON file?

I tried to use Text file as 'Source' and JSON file as 'Sink' (inside "Copy data" step), but I am not able to map 'Source' and 'Sink'.
[image]

I also tried having the third step with JSON files as 'Source' and 'Sink', but I am not sure how  **@variables('myVariable')** should be carried into this step as it is not a text file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution by having the data type of JSON on next "Copy data" pointing to the text file (csv) that I used. Even though the file was originally created with DelimitedText (csv) file, when I pointed that same file, but using JSON format, it took it.